# UK Visa Refused - can I reapply immediately?

Tags: visas, uk, visa-refusals

I applied for the UK tourism visa.

I mentioned that I was going to travel only for 2 weeks. However I got rejected because I didn't mention in the application, that I was working, nor mentioned that my dad has a job also.

Although I gave them my dad's bank statement, they were worried that I might go to the UK and not come back, because I might not have enough funds to return to Egypt which is not true.

My mum wrote my application and she didn't know that she was supposed to put my dad's job or mine as well, or whether I stayed with my family or alone. I suspect that's the reason why the visa application got rejected.

I want to apply again for the visa because I want to visit my cousin - she lives there, plus I need to go on a vacation. I want to know whether it's possible for me to apply again for the visa now, or do I have to wait for another six months to reapply?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[Source on gov.uk](https://www.gov.uk/general-visit-visa/eligibility)

> You can apply for a General Visitor visa if you’re:

- 18 or over
- travelling to the UK for leisure (not work or study)
- able to support yourself for the duration of your trip
- not in transit to another country, except for Ireland, the Isle of Man or the Channel Islands
- able to pay for your return or onward journey

> I might go to the UK and not come back because I might not have enough funds to return to Egypt which is not true

That is your assumption. How do you intend to prove it to the visa officer ? You have to give proof to support your point.

- evidence that you can support yourself during your trip, eg bank statements or payslips for the last 6 months
- details of where you intend to stay and your travel plans - you shouldn’t pay for accommodation or travel until you get your visa

> dad's job or mine

As you are the one who is travelling, you have to reveal your financial situation, not your father's.

> wanted to visit my cousin, she lives there plus I need to go on a vacation

You cannot claim to take a vacation as a right and so demand a visa. You have to provide evidence to support your case. If you intend to stay with your cousin, then you will have to provide his(her) details too. If you decide to apply for a family visitor visa a letter of invitation from him(her) will be required.

> My mum wrote my application

Next time fill your application yourself.

Regarding reapplying(no need to wait for 6 months, I haven't seen any evidence for such till now), reapply with the proper documentation. Err on the side of caution and be diligent in providing proof to support your application. Check the link on gov.uk and follow it to the letter.

Comment: uh.. I think the OP just wanted to know whether he could apply a visa immediately or wait for another 6 months.

Comment: Just that info clearly wouldn't help him, because sending the same application over and over again, he'd be rejected over and over again...

Comment: @DumbCoder: That other post is from a different user.