# UK visa refused, now I want to reapply but didn't mention my family last time - what to do?

Tags: uk, visa-refusals, egyptian-citizens, deception

I applied for a tourist visa to UK. I am a student at university. I gave them proof that I am studying at my university. I got refused because he was not satisfied that I will go to UK and come to Egypt again and I didn't get him a document to prove that I will stay the next year in my university (I don't know how can to get that document). I have a British uncle who lives in London but when I was applying for the first time I wrote in my application that I don't have any family members in the UK. Now if I want to apply again what should I do? Can I make my uncle send me an invitation or  will that be too risky for me as that'll expose my previous lie? Will that get my application refused?

Comment: Can you shortly confirm that this is not a duplicate of http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/36755/uk-visa-rejected and you are not just ommitting some information in this question, and some in the other? That would provide some evidence to potential answer writers that their work is not in vein.

Comment: but my situation is much different , and i have other question about my situation with mu=y uncle

Comment: Are you intending to study in the UK, or is your university in Egypt?

Comment: I would imagine the document they are looking for to prove you will return to university is (for example) something showing that you are enrolled in a four year course and that you have only completed two years of it.

Comment: @DJClayworth and what u see in my second question about my family ?!

Answer (score 7):

In deciding whether or not to grant a visitor visa (i.e., entry clearance) to a visa national, considering the applicant's family already in the UK is important.  Based upon what you wrote, you were in a position to know that you had family in the UK when you made your application, and you were in a position to know that the information was significant.  Despite this, you did not disclose it.

Deliberate failure to disclose significant information is something that will get them VERY  upset for a long time.  If you get caught, they will go to Paragraph 320 of the rules and find one of the sub-paragraphs that applies.  It would most likely be (7B)(d) *using Deception in an application for entry clearance, leave to enter or remain, or in 
order to obtain documents from the Secretary of State or a third party required in support  of the application (whether successful or not);*

To your question: if you apply again and disclose family in the UK, in all likelihood you'll be caught.  And if you apply again and DO NOT disclose family in the UK, you will then have them after you for "exacerbating circumstances", because you have continually engaged in deception.  The penalty for that is a long term ban.  Plus it MIGHT make your uncle have problems inviting anyone else to visit.

For your other question:  It is also likely in addition to the refusal reason you gave that they determined you have no viable premise for visiting the UK at this point.  You'll need to think up something before they will approve your application.

These sorts of circumstances are best left to a regulated practitioner, like a member of the Law Society, and that's the best recommendation for your next port of call.  There are about 350 accredited law firms with the specialised expertise you are after, you can look through the list at http://solicitors.lawsociety.org.uk/search/results?Pro=False&UmbrellaLegalIssue=LIUIMM&LegalIssue=LIIMN&AccreditedOnly=True&Language=

Comment: thank you for your help , but u don't tell me what exactly should i do , can i tell them that i don't include my family information because i was in a tourist trip will they Understand that or not ?! and i think i should tell them about my family in my next application in any way true ?

Comment: @heshamamerican, to the contrary, I told you *EXACTLY* what to do: please read the last paragraph of my answer.  You are far too vulnerable to be seeking further info on the net because you have specific circumstances!  Also please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: am sorry some words couldn't understand them , i understand that if i still in lie they may discover , if i told them the truth and in my next application give them the family information can i tell them any excuse for not writing that information in the last application ?!

Comment: @heshamamerican, The courts have already said that giving an excuse of any sort will not work.  As already pointed out, a competent and regulated solicitor will know what to tell them.  So which part of SEE A LAWYER do you not understand?

Comment: i understand what u mean now , do u any specialist we can ask him for this ?! ( person or place)  ?

Comment: Fair enough, answer amended to give the link.  There are a few others, if you cannot find one that suits you can ping me.  I wouldn't give a specific name in an answer because that would be spamming the site.

Comment: i really have been searching for someone to ask from a long time and i didn't find any one , please tell me how to ping you