# Egyptian student - was refused tourist visa from UK?

Tags: visas, uk, visa-refusals, tourist-visas, egyptian-citizens

I am an Egyptian student.

Last summer I applied for a tourist visa and I got refused because my bank statement when I applied showing the past 3 months were:

first month balance : 0 , and other two months 5.000 english pound

The other reason for refusal was that they needed a document to prove that I will stay in my college next year I already gave them a proof that am in college but how can I prove to them that I will be next year too??

Comment: possible duplicate of [UK visa refused, now I want to reapply but didn't mention my family last time - what to do?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/36760/uk-visa-refused-now-i-want-to-reapply-but-didnt-mention-my-family-last-time)

Comment: This is very hard to answer because there can be any number of reasons why visas are rejected. Good conjectures below, but we can never say for sure.

Answer (score 2):

Obviously, for every visa there are requirements, and if you don't meet them, you likely won't get the visa. There's no way around that.

So in this case, they wanted two things:

1. Evidence of cash in your bank statements to support yourself during the trip. They generally ask for the past 3 months to show that you haven't just dumped a large sum in to satisfy them.  Going from ZERO to 5,000 would raise questions like that - it's not a normal transaction flow.  You're going to have to either write an accompanying letter explaining the account history behaviour, or wait another month to show then that your last 3 months have decent cash.
2. They want evidence that you're going to return to Egypt - ie to study.  Have you enrolled in next year yet? If so, the university will usually be able to provide a letter for you stating that you're enrolled for the next year.  They'll have done this many times for other students as well, so will know what to provide.

Comment: what you mean by accompanying letter explaning the account history behaviour ? , and in my university now am level 2 i will apply for visa in the summer if i ask my university for letter they will give me  a proof for the past year not for new one !!

Comment: Well the immigration people are going to be concerned about the sudden jump from 0 to 5000 - that's not normal for a bank account. If it's due to a new job or something, great, explain that in a letter. You might not need to, but it may help.

Comment: For the university, as I said - IF you are already enrolled for next year, ask you university for evidence of this. They're only going to give you 1) what you ask for and 2) what is possible. So if you're not enrolled, they can't help you.

Comment: what if i apply to study there !! will be more easy ?

Comment: Study - in England? That's a different question entirely, and studying questions are off-topic on this site, sorry.

Comment: can u tell me ur opinion in that situation please ! http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/36760/uk-visa-refused-now-i-want-to-reapply-but-didnt-mention-my-family-last-time

Comment: Follow the answers on that post. I don't know any more than what I wrote above, and what's on the other post.

Comment: if u in my situation will u tell them in your new application about ur uncle !

Comment: Oh that question is you too? You changed your name!  I don't know, I probably wouldn't get into that situation, all I know is - don't lie on an application, ever.

Comment: You lied the first time. If you come out now with the truth, you have to give very genuine reason as to why you lied the first time. Prove, show your intent that you will return back, family ties or anything which shows you will come back. Remember that the visa process is getting strict, so the less ambiguous your application is, more are the chances that you will get the visa. Don't try to get a visa hook or by crook. It will damage your chances of getting a visa again to any other country.

Comment: @Mark Mayo i don't change my name that's new question and i want only to take your opinion , thanks for your help :)

Comment: @user3380869 Mark means you changed your name on StackExchange - from "hesham american" to "user3380869". Please don't do that - it confuses people.

Comment: @DumbCoder can u tell me in your opinion what's genuine reason for that !

Comment: @DJClayworth thanks for you but i really didn't change my name i just log in now by facebook