# What documents do I need to carry for second visit to UK on multiple entry C-Tourist visa?

Tags: uk, multiple-entry

My first visit was in July for a conference that lasted 3 days, and because I had school and work to come back to, I returned to my home country without having visited any of the places I wanted to visit in the UK. My visa was granted on the basis of the invitation to the conference, and the organizers arranged my accommodation as well.
I am going back in October during a 10-day vacation, and I will be staying with my mum's cousin in Luton during that time. I will be carrying an updated Certificate of No Objection from work and Proof of Studentship from my school.

My question is, do I need a letter from my mum's cousin stating that I'll be staying with them during this time since I don't have a hotel booking? Is there any other document I should expect to be asked of me by border control?

It may be important to note I did not mention any family in the UK when I initially applied for my visa.

Comment: Did you specifically answer ‘no’ to the question about whether you have family in the UK? If so, you could be facing a serious problem since this could well be viewed as deception or false representation, leading to your visa being cancelled and a likely ban. https://assets.publishing.service.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/674000/GGFR-Section-3-v29.0EXT.PDF

Comment: Related question https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/36760/uk-visa-refused-now-i-want-to-reapply-but-didnt-mention-my-family-last-time

Comment: I answered no to the question as this person was my mother's cousin and I didn't know about them at the time. In this case, should I be looking to stay at a hotel during my stay?

Answer (score 1):

As far as documents to bring with you goes, the official advice is to carry with you the same documents you’d use to apply for a visa to show to Immigration if asked. This would include for example, documents to prove:

- intention to leave at the end of the visit (such as ties to home, return ticket)
- sufficient funds to cover all reasonable costs in relation to the visit without working or accessing public funds. It is probably normal, although not explicitly required, to be able to prove accommodation; if you don’t have somewhere pre-booked you should have a credible plan for arranging accommodation on arrival and sufficient funds to do it. ‘Sufficient funds’ is subjective, depending on what you plan to do during the trip and where you plan to stay. Obviously, you’ll need more funds if you’ll be paying for accommodation than if you were staying with relatives.

During the landing interview the Immigration Officer may ask whether you have family in the UK. You must tell the truth, if asked, see V9 https://www.gov.uk/guidance/immigration-rules/immigration-rules-appendix-v-visitor-rules and related question [UK visa refused, now I want to reapply but didn't mention my family last time - what to do?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/36760/uk-visa-refused-now-i-want-to-reapply-but-didnt-mention-my-family-last-time)

Comment: The very first advice that this answer refers to is not related to this situation  imho. That advice is for people who go to the U.K. visa free. You certainly are not advised to carry the whole set of application supporting documents every time you visit the U.K. on a multiple entry visa obtained long ago.

Comment: @Hanky Panky I’d agree, except in this case the original premise for the visa was based on a 3rd party providing support. Also, July isn’t ‘long ago’. IMHO the premise for the return visit is sufficiently different to warrant being cautious - I’m not suggesting a whole raft of documents, but I do think proving finances and intention to leave is important (as it might well be for other destinations eg US or Schengen). UK visit visas are almost always multi entry with 6 months’ validity but it doesn’t always follow that a repeat visit is granted at the port of entry.

Comment: Also, the OP learning of a family member between the two visits may raise questions.