# Reapply for UK PLAB visa after refusal

Tags: visas, uk, visa-refusals, pakistani-citizens

I am a Pakistani citizen and applied for PLAB 2 UK visa (for 6 months) on 15th October 2015 and was refused a visa based on the fact that the visa officer was not satisfied that I would leave the UK at the end of my visit.

My contract at work expires 2nd December 2015 and my exam is on 6th January 2016. I stated in the application form I will be staying for 3 months and I will be flying to UK on 1st December 2015. I work on an annual contract basis and according to the hospital policy the contract is renewed only a month before expiry.

So there was no way for me to show them my new contract which would be renewed in November 2015. Now my exam fee and the my career are at jeopardy. I assumed they would understand that I will be staying for at least 3 months because in case I fail my exam I will re-apply from within UK within that valid 6 month period of the visa.

I have not been given any right of appeal or administrative review. Please guide on when can i make my new application. My new contract is ready now.

Comment: Try rewriting it is normal lettering.  ALL CAPS IS SHOUTING, and we are not the people to be shouting at.

Comment: Please don't post in all caps, I fixed your formatting. If you now have a new contract you can reapply with this and any other new evidence. In order for us to be any more help we'd need more details. You may also find the answers to [this question](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/36755/uk-visa-refused-can-i-reapply-immediately?rq=1) useful.