# I was refused a UK short-term study visa. Can I reapply immediately?

Tags: visas, uk, visa-refusals, study

I applied for a short term study visa. I got admission to an Oxford summer course. In my visa application, I gave all the supportive documents. But my visa has been refused by stating that the bank statement of my father and his personal income does not match plus I didn't give my fathers employment status!

Kindly tell me that should I apply immediately again by stating all the unclear origins of the application clearly?

Comment: It won't help very much but questions about these kinds of visas go in the Expats site, this site specializes in Appendix V.

Comment: Voting to reopen -- the question explicitly says it is about a "summer course", which would be the kind of short-term travel we're about here -- defintely not about relocating for any extended period of time.

Comment: Very similar (possible dupe) of: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/36755/uk-visa-refused-can-i-reapply-immediately

Comment: a short term study visa for summer or any other season, is not a visitor visa. It is issued under paragraph 57A of the rules, which says... "*A57A. These Rules apply to persons who wish to study in the UK as a short-term student for up to and including 6 months or, for persons aged 18 and over, for up to and including 11 months for English language study only.*" Visitor rules are different and make different assumptions, different topologies, etc.  **Reopen votes are misconceived and uninformed answers will not help the OP.**

Answer (score 3):

**Can I reapply immediately?**

Yes, though whether wise to do so may in part depend on the exact wording of your refusal letter. However given *I got admission to an Oxford summer course* (ie time is of the essence) and what you state of the refusal reasons (ie basically the issues were documentary) I think you have little choice but to do so.

And yes, at the very least any further application should address the stated issues:

I] explain any apparent discrepancies between bank statements and personal income for your father, and
2] state your father's employment status.

You may also wish to consult a *[reputable](https://www.lawsociety.org.uk/)* agent (such as an immigration specialist who is a member of the UK Law Society) who should at least be able to ensure that the paperwork for any further application is in order prior to submission.

Please also note that for any more specific question about UK study visas [Expatriates](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) may be a better place to ask than here.

General guidance from [GOV.UK](https://www.gov.uk/government/uploads/system/uploads/attachment_data/file/514584/Short-term-student-guidance-v3-ext.pdf).